# SSRS Report Repeating Columns across multiple pages

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools, rdl

As a very simplified example, suppose I have the following DataSet I'm trying to create an SSRS report (.rdl file) from:

```
TabOrdinal  TabName     EndDate     Value
1           First Tab   1/1/2018    141
1           First Tab   1/1/2018    297
1           First Tab   1/1/2018    309
1           First Tab   1/1/2018    705
1           First Tab   1/1/2018    398
1           First Tab   1/2/2018    309
1           First Tab   1/2/2018    753
1           First Tab   1/2/2018    641
1           First Tab   1/2/2018    806
1           First Tab   1/2/2018    177
1           First Tab   1/2/2018    503
1           First Tab   1/3/2018    653
1           First Tab   1/3/2018    717
1           First Tab   1/3/2018    969
1           First Tab   1/3/2018    631
1           First Tab   1/3/2018    614
1           First Tab   1/3/2018    160
1           First Tab   1/4/2018    463
1           First Tab   1/4/2018    997
1           First Tab   1/4/2018    87
1           First Tab   1/4/2018    378
1           First Tab   1/4/2018    972
1           First Tab   1/4/2018    212
2           Second tab  1/4/2018    873
2           Second tab  1/4/2018    525
2           Second tab  1/4/2018    693
2           Second tab  1/4/2018    48
2           Second tab  1/4/2018    20
2           Second tab  1/4/2018    685
2           Second tab  1/4/2018    688
```

And I have created the following groupings in my Report:

**Top-Level Row Group:**

```
Name: Tab
Group On: [TabName]
Page Breaks: Between Each Group
```

**In Code:**

```
<TablixMember>
  <Group Name="Tab">
    <GroupExpressions>
      <GroupExpression>=Fields!TabName.Value</GroupExpression>
    </GroupExpressions>
    <PageBreak>
      <BreakLocation>Between</BreakLocation>
    </PageBreak>
    <PageName>=Fields!TabName.Value</PageName>
  </Group>
  <SortExpressions>
    <SortExpression>
      <Value>=Fields!TabOrdinal.Value</Value>
    </SortExpression>
  </SortExpressions>
  <TablixMembers>
  ...
  </TablixMembers>
</TablixMember>
```

And a **Column Group**:

```
Name: EndDate
Group On: [EndDate]
```

**In Code:**

```
<TablixMember>
  <Group Name="EndDate">
    <GroupExpressions>
      <GroupExpression>=Fields!EndDate.Value</GroupExpression>
    </GroupExpressions>
  </Group>
  <SortExpressions>
    <SortExpression>
      <Value>=Fields!EndDate.Value</Value>
    </SortExpression>
  </SortExpressions>
  <TablixMembers>
    <TablixMember />
  </TablixMembers>
</TablixMember>
```

Now, what I was HOPING would happen, given the sample data I presented, would be that my report would look somewhat as follows:

**Tab1:**

```
1/1/2018       1/2/2018      1/3/2018     1/4/2018
<data>         <data>        <data>       <data>
```

**Tab2:**

```
1/4/2018
<data>
```

However, I don't know why, but my second tab is including empty columns for all the same dates that existed on the first tab, so the second tab looks as follows:

**Tab2:**

```
<empty column>       <empty column>     <empty column>     1/4/2018
<empty column>       <empty column>     <empty column>     <data>
```

How can I have it so the report knows to reset the date columns with each tab?

I hope this makes sense, but, if not, please let me know and I'll try and explain further.

Comment: Screenshots of the report design would be more helpful to determine why the grouping isn't working. I've never had to resort to editing the XML to get a report to work.

Comment: Sorry, @StevenWhite, I completely agree, but my company's policy makes taking screenshots near-impossible :/. In words, my report has 2 columns. The second column is the `Date` grouping mentioned above and ALL the rows use the `Tab` grouping mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is displaying to the right is because you're grouping on the `EndDate`, but the end date already has three values before `1/4/2018`.

Perhaps you can modify your SQL query and add a `ROW_NUMBER()` like the following:

```
 ... ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TabName ORDER BY TabName, EndDate) AS rn
```

Then in your column group, just group by rn. You may need to modify the `ROW_NUMBER` portion a little bit to make sure your values are getting set correctly. I've modified to only partition by `TabName`. I think that's what you want.

In order to hide a textbox without a value, I'm sure there are multiple ways to go about it. One way I was successful was to right-click on the column and go to column visibility. From there I added the expression - `=ReportItems!TextBoxName.Value = NOTHING`... Of course you will have to use the correct name for your "data".

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll try it and let you know, but I'm just wondering. Will I then have 3 columns AFTER the end-date in this case?
Can you think of, maybe, a filter / visibility change I could make to possibly fix this otherwise?

Comment: As I suspected, the first solution just moved the column to the beginning of the second tab, but your edit with the `ReportItems` worked a charm!!
THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.